# Query SQL Database and send email for each record - PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to query a SQL database and then loop through each of the data sets to send an email with data.

Below is a sample data set - so for record 1, my goal is to send an email to `powershell1@whyme.com` with the policy information for that specific record and so on for the remaining records.

```
PolicyNumber            PSN       TransactionPremium    EmailAddress              Record
ABC DE3 0000012183 00   8636692   14109                 powershell1@whyme.com     1
FGH JI3 0000012183 00   8636693  -14199                 powershell2@whyme.com     2
KLM NO3 0000000774 03   8556541   -1664                 powershell3@whyme.com     3
PRS TU3 0000000943 03   8579971   0                     powershell4@whyme.com     4
HCA HO3 0000000969 03   8603944   -1425                 powershell5@whyme.com     5
```

But after returning the data from the query, I cannot figure out how to loop through each record and send the email.

```
$Instance = "sqlinstancename"
$Database = "databasename"
$SQL = @'
SELECT TOP (5) PolicyNumber, PSN, CAST(TransactionPremium AS DECIMAL(19,4)) AS TransactionPremium, EmailAddress
FROM dbo.TableName ORDER BY BatchDate DESC
'@

Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance $Instance -Database $Database -Query $SQL
```

I assume it will be something along the lines of:

```
ForEach ($i in i)
{
Send-MailMessage -From "noreply@companyx.com" -To $EmailAddress -Subject "Test" -BodyAsHTML $PolicyNumber"
}
```

Could I get some assistance on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all is well with the query, a loop to send the emails may look something like this:

```
$Rows = Query-DataBase Query <Query> -Instance <Server\Instance> -Database <DBName>

ForEach( $Row in $Rows)
{
    $EmailParams = @{
        $From       = 'noreply@companyx.com'
        $To         = $Row.EmailAddress
        $Subject    = 'test'
        $BodyAsHtml = $true
        $Body       = $Row.PolicyNumber
        $SMTPServer = 'YourSMTPServerFQDN'
    }
    Send-EmailMessage @EmailParams
}
```

Note: I'm using splatting which you can read about in [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1). Splatting helps a lot with formatting and readability. That said, this is really just referencing the desired properties in the loop and therefore per each item then sending the email. As such it can easily be expanded so you can get the body, subject, or whatnot correct.

Comment: Hey - I appreciate the response but I'm not sure that answers my question.  I don't have an issue connecting to the SQL database - my issue lies in taking the data set that is returned and looping through each email address to send out an email to the recipient.

Comment: I'm sorry I must have had a brain fart.  That's actually quite easy.  If you give me a minute I can cook up an example.